# How can I pass my custom attributes to my redirect url in Azure AD App?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am authenticating user with Azure AD authentication in MVC Application but I have some dynamic parameters to pass to my redirect uri. Is there any way to pass those parameters other than Query string, Because query string works only with static parameters.

I need to pass some properties to authentication so that I can get them back to my redirected uri.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly refer to the official document below:

> Azure AD applications can now register and use redirect (reply) URIs
>   with static query parameters (such as
>   https://contoso.com/oauth2?idp=microsoft) for OAuth 2.0 requests.
>   Dynamic redirect URIs are still forbidden as they represent a security
>   risk, and this cannot be used to retain state information across an
>   authentication request - for that, use the state parameter.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#redirect-uris-can-now-contain-query-string-parameters